# Android Popupwindow displays popup twice

Tags: android

I am trying to create a pop up window on click of a button using PopupWindow class , the code works but the pop up comes 2 times when i touch the button once

I have tried using a counter variable to limit the number of popups and reset it whenever the popup.dismiss function gets called , but then the second pop up comes up after the first gets dismissed

device - oneplus 3t(A3003)
android version - 9.0

Visit_details.java

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_visit_details);
    DatabaseReference custRef, visitRef, order_dateRef, statusRef;
    Button update_status = findViewById(R.id.btn_update_status);
    private PopupWindow status_popup;
    RelativeLayout mRelativeLayout;
    statusRef = visitRef.child("status");
    update_status.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(final View v)
        {
            statusRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener()
            {

                @Override
                public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot)
                {
                    String old_status = dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class);
                    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                    View customView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.update_status_popup, null);

                    status_popup = new PopupWindow(getApplicationContext());
                    status_popup.setContentView(customView);
                    status_popup.setHeight(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
                    status_popup.setWidth(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
                    status_popup.setOutsideTouchable(true);
                    status_popup.setAnimationStyle(R.style.Animation);
                    status_popup.setFocusable(true);

                    RadioButton live = customView.findViewById(R.id.rb_live_pop);
                    RadioButton lost = customView.findViewById(R.id.rb_lost_pop);
                    RadioButton closed = customView.findViewById(R.id.rb_closed_pop);

                    status_popup.showAtLocation(mRelativeLayout, Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
                    statuspopup_count++;

                    if (old_status.equals("live"))
                    {
                        live.setChecked(true);
                    } else if (old_status.equals("lost"))
                    {
                        lost.setChecked(true);
                    } else if (old_status.equals("closed"))
                    {
                        closed.setChecked(true);
                    }

                    live.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
                    {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v)
                        {
                            new_status = "live";
                            status_popup.dismiss();
                        }
                    });

                    lost.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
                    {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v)
                        {
                            new_status = "lost";
                            status_popup.dismiss();
                        }
                    });
                    closed.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
                    {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v)
                        {
                            new_status = "closed";
                            status_popup.dismiss();
                        }
                    });
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError)
                {
                }
            });
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Please reformat you're code properly

Comment: @CodeREDInnovations is it better now?

Comment: You are calling status_popup = new PopupWindow(getApplicationContext()); in onDataChange. First you need to make sure that the callback onDataChanged is not being called twice. This might be the reason why your popup is appearing twice! To figure it out, add a Log.i() in on DataChange to see how many times it's being called

Comment: @MervinHemaraju thank you...moving the addEventValueListener out of the button's onclick listener fixed the issue...thanks again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed it by moving the addEventValueListener out of the button's onclick listener fixed the issue
Thanks @MervinHemaraju for pointing it out

Comment: Glad i could help mate :)